# In Github Manual action, unable to get the selected branch

Tags: github-actions

it is possible to select a branch when a manual dispatch Github action flow is used, but then it is always run with a default branch instead of branch selected.

Neither of these actions

```
  - name: "Checkout source code"
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

or

```
  - name: "Checkout source code"
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      ref: {{github.ref}}
```

checks out from the branch selected by user. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first case doesn't work because it is using your default branch.

And the second one you need the `$` before your context env var.

It should be `${{ github.ref }}` instead of `{{ github.ref }}`.